# JavasScript - destroy Sortable.js elements

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I want to destroy my Sortable.js elements.

Initialization:

('Item' is object which contains my sortable elements)

I need to initialize multiple sets at once, so I'm storing it into an array

```
SortableTiles[index] = Sortable.create(item, {
    animation: 150,
    swapThreshold: 1,
});
```

This works just fine, but I'm unable to destroy them. In Web console i tried for test

> SortableTiles[0].sortable('destroy') - *Uncaught TypeError:
>   SortableTiles[0].sortable is not a function*

and variants of this, but all with the same result.

[Sortable.js Github repository](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sortable.js` has the method `destroy` on `sortable` class instance, so you can call it on that directly:

```
SortableTiles[0].destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anurag Srivastava, 
It was my fault, when I typed it into console it said "undefined", so I haven't tried it.